# How to open the child form from another child form inside an MDI from?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an MDI form and 2 child forms
What i want is, when i click on menu button in MDI, it should open the Login form, when the login is through, from the login form, on button click, I want to close the login form and open the second child form
Here is the code i am trying, but it does not open inside the MDI, it opens outside. Please help

```
this.Close();
frmAdmin frm = new frmAdmin();
frm.MdiParent = this.ParentForm;
frm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
 frm.Show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not call second form from `Login` form. Open `Login` form as modal dialog, and return login result to the parent form, which will "make decision" based on the login result and open second form.

```
// Login function in main form
using (var login = new LoginForm())
{
    if (login.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Ok)
    {
        var admin = new AdminForm
        {
            MdiParent = this;
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }

        admin.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        // do something when login fails
    }
}
```

With approach above your `Login` form will remain with only responsibility to login users.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the code as follows

```
frmAdmin frm = new frmAdmin();
frm.MdiParent = this.ParentForm;
this.close();
frm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
 frm.Show();
```